# Having to run readlines() followed by read(). Is there a more efficient approach

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

this feels like a daft problem but here goes.

I have a lot of data files to process, each file has a variable number of lines of preamble before the main data.  Processing requires that I find some values in the preamble and then read the main data into a pandas df.

From the preamble I need the number of lines  which I can do:

```
with open(csvfile) as f:
data = f.readlines()
for num, line in enumerate(data, 0):
    if end_preamble in line:
        lines = num
```

I also need to find some values in the preamble which are needed to process the subsequent data.  I can also do this:

```
with open(csvfile) as f:
    data = f.read()
term1 = re.finall...(regex term)..
```

both of these work, but `read()` doesn't return line numbers since (as I understand) it interprets the text as a single line.  Conversely `readlines()` can't be regexed for a string (I think because it's not stored - but I may well be wrong).

I have hack for now of:

```
with open(csvfile) as f:
    data = f.read(250)
lines = data.count('\n')
term1 = re.finall.....
```

This works since most of the time the preamble is less than 250 bytes long. But if I have a file with a very short or very long preamble this won't work.

The files aren't huge so I can use `readlines()` and also use `read()`  but reading the file twice seems like an inefficient way to accomplish what seems a relatively trivial task.  Is there a more efficient method of combining the two needs?

Answer (score 2):

Use `readline()` instead of `readlines()`. It will allow you to read any amount of rows but only preamble of the file (not the whole file):

```
with open(csvfile) as f:
    num = 0
    while end_preamble not in f.readline():
        num += 1
```

As a result you get `num` which is the number of the last row in the preamble.

EDIT.

If you want to open file only once (error-prone way) you may do it like this:

```
with open(csvfile, mode='rb') as f:
    preamble = b''
    line = f.readline()
    while end_preamble.encoded('UTF-8') not in line:
        preamble += line
    preamble = preamble.decoded('UTF-8')

    data = pandas.read_table(f, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks - that is much more resilient than my version.  I still have to open `csvfile` twice.  Im wondering if there is a way to do it in one step.

Comment: @nick.sculthorpe Opening file twice is not a problem. It is a very common operation.